# Не устанавливается библиотека yfinance

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, conda

В командной строке вижу такую инфу по поводу conda environment, которой раньше не было:

```
C:\Users\Сергей>python

Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

В результате не работает pip

Например, при попытке установить `pip install yfinance==0.1.52`
выдает следующее:

```
>>> `pip install yfinance==0.1.52`

  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install yfinance==0.1.52
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Да и вообще после появления этой записи (по поводу не активированной conda environment) такой же результат дают другие команды. Например:

```
>>> python

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'python' is not defined
>>>
```

Что можно сделать?

Comment: И правильно ругается, вы вошли в режим интерактивного интерпретатора, там выполняется код на питоне, а `pip` **нужно выполнять в командной строке**: `C:\Users\Сергей>pip install yfinance==0.1.52`. Аналогично и для `python`, ругается на `name 'python' is not defined` т.к. нет такой сущности (тип, функция и т.п.) в интерпретаторе.

Answer (score 1):

`pip` нужно выполнять в командной строке:

```
C:\Users\Сергей> pip install yfinance==0.1.52
```

---

Если `pip` недоступен, то нужно в переменную окружения `PATH` добавить папку питона `Scripts` (там будет `pip.exe`), например такой путь:

```
C:\Users\Сергей\Anaconda3\Scripts
```

И после перезапуска консоли `pip` будет доступен, т.к. командной строке будут доступны файлы из указанной в `PATH` папке

---

Еще `pip` можно вызвать через команду `python -m <модуль>`:

```
C:\Users\Сергей> python -m pip install yfinance==0.1.52
```